# Is OpenLDAP support attributes with null values?

Tags: ldap, openldap, opendj

Is there any way to create LDAP attribute with null values? Because in our environment our custom application will update the value of that attribute.

Comment: An LDAP attribute with nothing but a null value is empty, or absent. The API doesn't distringuish between these two conditions. If the attribute is defined in the schema for the object class, and you have permission, you can set it, whether absent, empy, present, ...

Answer (score 1):

As EJP said, no value in an attribute means the attribute is absent (or to be deleted with some update operations).

Some syntaxes, such as `IA5String`, support a value that is an empty string.
But this is not the case for `DirectoryString` which is the most used syntax for attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be too late for you! There is an overlay in OpenLDAP Gold Edition that automatically gets rid of empty string values for the DirectoryString syntax.